# Подскажите как решить проблему в css

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн

Делаю форму регистрации, при нажатии на поля текст, текст из поля поднимается вверх и если он прошел проверку браузером по type ( :valid ) то остается верху. Проблема заключается в поле email если некорректно введен email то текст падает на введенный текс в поле ввода с другими полями такой проблемы нет.
Вот мой код

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: white;
}

form {
    text-align: left;
}

label {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

label .label-text {
    color: grey;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 14px;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-34px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-34px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-34px);
    transform: translateY(-34px);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

label input {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F5F7;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 260px;
    
}

label input:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c3d2eb;
}

label input:focus + .label-text {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 13px;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
    transform: translateY(-44px);
}

label input:valid + .label-text {
    font-size: 13px;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
    transform: translateY(-44px);
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <label>    
    <input type="text" class="nick" required autofocus/>    
    <div class="label-text">Никнейм</div>
    </label>
    <label>    
    <input type="email" class="email" required />    
    <div class="label-text">E-mail</div>
    </label>
    <label>    
    <input type="password" class="pass" required />    
    <div class="label-text">Пароль</div> 
     </label>
    <label>    
    <input type="password" class="pass2" required />    
    <div class="label-text">Повторите пароль</div> 
     </label>
    <button class="btn btn-reg">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    <div class="social_networks_form">
        <a href="">
            <div class="element"><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <div class="element"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <div class="element"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <a href="register" class="btn-vhod">Уже есть аккаунт</a>
</div>
```

Поменять тип input ( email ) не могу

Answer (score 1):

Потому что браузер проверяет и получает ответ, что неправильная запись в форме и возвращает стили.
Попробуйте прописать отдельно стили для вариантов, когда значение неверно.

```
 input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) {...}
```

Добавьте:

```
label input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) + .label-text {
font-size: 13px;
-moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
-ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
transform: translateY(-44px);
}
```

а также добавьте пустой placeholder во **ВСЕ** input

```
<input type="email" class="email" required placeholder=" "/>
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: white;
}

form {
    text-align: left;
}

label {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

label .label-text {
    color: grey;
    cursor: text;
    font-size: 14px;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-34px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-34px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-34px);
    transform: translateY(-34px);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

label input {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F3F5F7;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 260px;
    
}

label input:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c3d2eb;
}

label input:focus + .label-text {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 13px;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
    transform: translateY(-44px);
}

label input:valid + .label-text {
    font-size: 13px;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
    transform: translateY(-44px);
}

label input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) + .label-text {
font-size: 13px;
-moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
-ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
transform: translateY(-44px);
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <label>    
    <input type="text" class="nick" placeholder=" " required autofocus/>    
    <div class="label-text">Никнейм</div>
    </label>
    <label>    
    <input type="email" class="email" placeholder=" " required />    
    <div class="label-text">E-mail</div>
    </label>
    <label>    
    <input type="password" class="pass" placeholder=" " required />    
    <div class="label-text">Пароль</div> 
     </label>
    <label>    
    <input type="password" class="pass2" placeholder=" " required />    
    <div class="label-text">Повторите пароль</div> 
     </label>
    <button class="btn btn-reg">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    <div class="social_networks_form">
        <a href="">
            <div class="element"><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <div class="element"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <div class="element"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <a href="register" class="btn-vhod">Уже есть аккаунт</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Если написать так label .email:invalid + .label-text {
    font-size: 13px;
    -moz-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-44px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-44px);
    transform: translateY(-44px);
} тогда текст email будет всегда вверху и не будет этой анимации подьема

Comment: @lazer361, тогда используйте 

     input:invalid:not(:placeholder-shown) {...}

и в input добавьте 

 <input type="email" class="email" required placeholder=" " />